# After I change name format, I can't insert data into SQL

Tags: asp-classic

In my ASP program I use `input` text field to input my date (yyyy,mm,dd) and for my previous input field, I can input data successfully.

> field format : ( a_year , a_month , a_day )  insert to SQL

But now, when I change to

```vb
name=" & a & "_Year
name=" & a & "_Month
name=" & a & "_Day
```

then I can't insert to my SQL now but I need this format to use my JavaScript calendar.

Does someone know how to make it right?

Code for the input form:

```
response.Write "<td align=left ><input type=text name=" & a & "_Year maxLength=4 size=4 value='' >Year</td>" 
response.Write "<td align=left ><input type=text name=" & a & "_Month maxLength=2 size=2 value='' >Month</td>" 
response.Write "<td align=left ><input type=text name=" & a & "_Day maxLength=2 size=2 value='' >Day</td>
```

My SQL insert:

```
Dim mDate 

" mDate = request.form("a_Year") & "/" & request.form("a_Month") & "/" & request.form("a_Day") "
```

Comment: Please show us the ASp and SQL code you use.

Comment: If you Response.Write(name) what do you see?

Comment: tried but   nothing shown

Comment: Are you getting any errors when the code executes?  The `name="...` bit just doesn't make any sense.

Comment: What does response.write(a) show?

Comment: @Luk Instead of posting code as a comment, please edit it into your question in the future

Comment: Please try this: response.write(request.form). This will show you all variables and their values, so you can process them.

Comment: no error display , it mean no data pass into databse     i check it using  response.write mSQL
response.End   and no date value return...

Comment: So why do you need to use name=" & a & "_Year etc in your input form.  Can't you just code it as name=a_Year.  Also, should you be using commas rather than forward slashes to separate your form values in mDate?

Comment: becoz i need to use the JS function  , and i need & a &  to fit my field box for user who select the calendar  , at first , i use a_year which can pass value successfully

Comment: Are you saying that the "a" is a literal string rather than a variable?  in which case try putting the "a" in double quotes, ie & "a" & "_Year